# Количество чоканий за столом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вообщем, нужно создать **функцию** с одним аргументом - (кол-во человек).
Далее, нужно чтобы функция могла вычислить кол-во ***"чоканье"*** с кол-вом людей, учитывая, что каждый "чокнулся" с каждым другим человеком. А также "чокаться" с самим с собой запрещено!

Не спрашивайте, откуда ко мне пришла такая идея...)

Пока что так, сделал проверку, если число равно 2, то в конце вычитаем 1, потому что факториал 2 = 1 * 2, а если ещё и убираем n, то остается 0...
Но сама функция пока вычисляет неправильно(

```
import math

def speech(n):
    if n == 2:
        x = (math.factorial(n)) - 1
        print(x)
    else:
        x = (math.factorial(n)) - n
        print(x)

speech(4)
```

Comment: Желательно с комментариями ещё)
Мне главное понять как это реализовывается

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема? Если число людей за столом N, то рисуя квадрат N на N понимаем, что число рукопожатий/чоканий равно N квадрат минус N (диагональ: сам с собой чокнуться нельзя).

Comment: @AK «сам с собой чокнуться нельзя»  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6NtmPuVOWI&feature=youtu.be&t=60 :)

Comment: @jfs Ну, это упрощает задачу Мне [вот эта](https://habr.com/en/post/463391/) понравилась про наливающего, говорящего тост и про нарезающего закуску.

Comment: У меня такое впечатление, что никто не хочет подумать над алгоритмом. Матрица симметрична относительно диагонали, если участник с номером 2 чокается с участником номер 20 -- то это тоже самое, что и участник номер 20 чокнулся с участником номер 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно помню комбинаторику, то вам нужно количество сочетаний из `n` по 2.

Погуглил формулу, кажется, должно быть как-то так:

```
from math import factorial

def speech(n):
    nfac = factorial(n)
    nmfac = factorial(n-2)
    mfac = 2 # factorial(2)
    res = nfac / (nmfac * mfac)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Отлично!)
А если не трудно, то не могли бы ещё пояснения написать, всё же я не столь опытный)

Comment: И кстати следует сделать проверку, так как, если задать аргумент 0 или 1, то выдавалась ошибка, но это уже просто

Comment: Ну, просто существует готовая формула, для подобных ситуаций. Есть такой раздел математики - "комбинаторика", и в нём ваши "чоканья" называются "сочетания из N по 2". По 2 - потому что в каждом чоканье участвуют два человека. Если бы вы хотели узнать каким количеством способов N человек могут сообразить на троих, то это были бы уже сочетания по 3. Формулу можно посмотреть, например, здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Сокращается до `n * (n-1) / 2`, и проблема с `n=0`, `n=1` решается сама собой.

Comment: @extrn , Вау! оказывается намного проще...) А как ты к этому пришёл?

Comment: @lakvak ну `n! = 1*2*...*(n-2)*(n-1)*n`. `(n-2)! = 1*2*...*(n-2)`. Сокращаем - остается `(n-1)*n`. Можно иначе к результату придти: первый чокнулся с `n-1`, второй, кроме того, что чокнулся с первым (уже посчитано) еще с `n-2`, и т.д. Итого `1+2+3+...+(n-1) = n * (n-1) / 2`

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется, тут вообще не нужен факториал как таковой:

```
def choks(len):
    return int((len * (len - 1)) / 2)
```

элементарная формула

Comment: Да, уже решили также сверху)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
def speech (n):
    x= math.factorial(n)-n
    print(x)
```

Проще говоря факториал числа N минус число N.

Comment: Ну во первых не правильно вычисляет, а во вторых как ты выведешь локальную переменную?

Comment: То есть вывести можно, но вычисляет не правильно

Comment: def speech(n):
    x = (n**n)-n
    print(x)

speech(3)

Вот так выводится, но неправильные значения

Comment: Но ведь факториал числа n - это СОВСЕМ не то же самое, что n ** n

Comment: @Xander , именно! Я о том же. Посмотри мои правки в коде, может сможешь помочь поправить функцию

Comment: @Лаврентий Палыч , попробуй в функцию дать аргумент 2, то она выведет 0, а это не правильно. Или к примеру 4, он выведет вообще 20

Comment: @lakvak почему не правильно?
!2 = 1*2 
speech = !2-2

Comment: @ЛаврентийПалыч ну сам подумай, ведь если будет 2 человека, то не может быть 0 "чоканий"))